# Last 3 digits of $3^{3^{3^3}}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am trying to find the last $3$ digits of $\,3^{\large 3^{3^3}}$, i.e. $\,3^{\large 3^{3^3}}\! \bmod 1000$.

My idea is to apply Euler's totient function in some way, but I am unsure on how to proceed. Would someone be able to help me out?

Comment: Just saw that, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prior $2$ answers omit hard calculations (too difficult mentally). Below is an easy way to do it *purely* mentally. *Nothing* is omitted. We use only $\rm B :=$ Binomial theorem and modular arithmetic.

$\!\!\bmod 200\!:\ \ \ \color{#c00}{3^{\large 20}}\equiv\, 1\,\ $ by $\,\ 9^{\large 10}\equiv\, (-1 + 10)^{\large 10}\overset{\rm B}\equiv  1 - {10}\cdot 10 + 5\cdot 9\cdot 10^{\large 2} \equiv 4401\equiv 1,\,$  so

$\!\! \bmod 1000\!:\ 3^{\large 100}\!\equiv 1\, $ by $\, ( \color{#c00}{3^{\large 20}})^{\large 5}\equiv (1\!+\!200k)^{\large 5}\overset{\rm B}\equiv 1 + 5\cdot 200k\equiv 1,\,$ therefore

$ 3^{\large 3^{\large 3^{\Large 3}}}\!\!\!\equiv 3^{\large \color{#0a0}{3^{\large 3^{\Large 3}}}\!\bmod{{100}}}\!\equiv 3^{\large\color{#0a0}{87}}\!\equiv 3(\color{#e94}{3^{\large 86}})\equiv  3(129)\equiv 387\ $ by  below:

$\ \ \ \bmod 100\!:\ \ \smash[t]{\color{#0a0}{3^{\large 3^{\LARGE 3}}}}\!\equiv\, \color{#0a0}{87}\,$ by $\, \color{#c00}{3^{\large 27}}\!\equiv 3^{\large 7}\!\equiv 3^{\large 3} 3^{\large 4}\equiv 27(1\!-\!20)\equiv 27\!-\!40,\ $ and

$\ \bmod 1000\!:\ \color{#e94}{3^{\large 86}}\!\equiv 129\,$ by $\, 9^{\large 43}\!\equiv (-1\!+\!10)^{\large 43}\overset{\rm B}\equiv -1\! +\! 43(10)\!-\!\underbrace{43(21)}_{\large \color{#d4f}3+10j}10^{\large 2}\!\equiv -1\!+\!430\!-\! \color{#d4f}300$

Comment: Nice and simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

First you should use the *Chinese remainder theorem*, i.e. determine the values $a$ and $b$ of $\;3^{3^{3^3}}$ modulo $8$ and $125$, then deduce its value modulo $1000$, with the formula deduced from a Bézout's identity between $8$ and  $125$: 
$$47\cdot 8-3\cdot 125=1$$
(found, e.g. by the *extended Euclidean algorithm*)
$$3^{3^{3^3}}\equiv b\cdot 47\cdot 8-a\cdot 3\cdot 125\mod 8\cdot125.$$

Now $a$ is easy to find since $3$ has order $2\bmod8$, so even powers of $3$ are congruent to $1$, odd powers congruent to $3$. Modulo $125$, it requires a little more work: as $\varphi(125)=100$, and $3$ is coprime to $125$, one has, by *Euler's theorem*,
$$3^{3^{3^3}}\equiv 3^{3^{3^3}\bmod100},$$
therefore we have  to compute the values of $\;3^{3^3}=3^{27}\bmod100$, which can be done by the *fast exponentiation algorithm* (‘square and divide’). Here is a layout. The last column contains the successive powers $P$ of $x$ (initially, $P=1$), until the exponent $n=27$ is attained
\begin{array}{rcll}
n&& \text{squaring}\;& P\\ \hline
27&& x & x \\
13 && x^2 & x^2\cdot x=x^3 \\ 
6 && x^4 & x^3 \\
3 && x^8 & x^8\cdot x^3 = x^{11} \\
1 && x^{16} & x^{16}\cdot x^{11}=x^{27}\\
\hline
\end{array}
You'll find $\;3^{3^3}\equiv 87\mod 100$. There remains to compute $\;3^{87}\bmod 125$, which can be done again with the fast exponentiation algorithm ($6$ squarings and $4$ multiplications mod. $125$).

It can be made a little faster using that $a^{87}\equiv a^{-13}=(a^{-1})^{13}\mod 125$. . As $3^{-1}\equiv 42\mod 125$, this amounts to $\;42^{13}\bmod 125$ ($3$ squarings, $2$ multiplications).

Comment: It looks correct, but I think every step cannot be done by hand, or at least deserves some justification (for instance showing why $(59050-1)^10\equiv 1\mod 1000$).

Comment: **Major oversight:** it doesn't   "come down to computing $\, n\equiv 3^{\large 27}\!\pmod{\!100}$" because after you compute $\,n\equiv\color{#c00}{ 87}\pmod{\!100}\,$ you still need to further compute $\,b\equiv 3^{\color{#c00}{\large 87}}\!\pmod{\!125},\,$ which is the most work of all (without any optimizations). Omitting any mention of that is very misleading. Likely there are (much) simpler solutions (e.g. using the Binomial Theorem or related techniques).

Comment: @BillDubuque/ 've changed my phrasing to make it unambiguous. Anyway, I only give hints.

Comment: The edit doesn't fix the fact that the "answer" omits any mention at all of  the most difficult (final) part of the computation, viz. computing $\, 3^{\large 87}\bmod{125}.\,$ I wouldn't be surprised if some readers completely miss that this step is required. It should be *explicitly* mentioned that you are leaving this (hardest) final step to the reader in order to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Glad to see that you clarified it (there is a typo in the final paragraph: $a^{\large 97}$ should be $a^{\large 87})\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: Oh! yes. Fixed. Thank you for pointing it!